# Python: Error in running If loop

Tags: python, if-statement

I have a code like this

```
ten=(1,7,8,10)
ten=np.array(ten)
nine=(3,6,9)
nine=np.array(nine)
lat=range(1,11)
p_new1=[]
H2O_vmr_new1=[]
level=range(1,91)
row=range(0,6)
for j in lat:
    if j in ten:
        print j
        for a in level:
            if((H2O_vmr[a]-H2O_vmr[a+1])/(p[a]-p[a+1]))-((H2O_vmr[a-1]-
        H2O_vmr[a])/(p[a-1]-p[a]))>.000001:
                p_new1.append(p[a])
                H2O_vmr_new1.append(H2O_vmr[a])
    elif j in nine:
        for a in level:
            if((H2O_vmr[a]-H2O_vmr[a+1])/(p[a]-p[a+1]))-((H2O_vmr[a-1]-
                H2O_vmr[a])/(p[a-1]-p[a]))>.000001:
                p_new1.append(p[a])
                H2O_vmr_new1.append(H2O_vmr[a])
```

only the first if loop is working that too it takes only the last value of 'j'(i tried printing 'j').second loop-'elif'(I tried 'if' instead of 'elif' also) is not working even.I'm really new to this.Any help will be appreciated.

Note:I have not posted the full code,since it is very long.I have only posted the part which is showing errors.

Comment: what is `level`? where did you define it? Your code is not complete to help you.

Comment: What is content of level?

Comment: "only the first if loop is working that too it takes only the last value of 'j'" what do you mean by that?

Comment: if values in `p` or `H2O_vmr` are ints, then given the compared value, there is a good chance your division yields 0.

Comment: I tried to print some words using print inside both the loops,only the first loop came out with the output..for the second loop there was no output

Comment: no p and H2O_vmr are lists which contains float values

Comment: You say it is showing error, what error is it showing exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your for loop works, there is no issue there. You haven't posted the values of `H2O_vmr` and `p` so I don't know what you're trying to do exactly.

If I was to make an assumption, I would say you're trying to access the loop index, and that might be the problem.

```
H2O_vmr[a+1]
```

I assume you're using `a+1` in an attempt to access the next index and using `a-1` in an attempt to access the previous index. This may be the reason for the confusion. `a+1` is not accessing the next index, instead it takes the value of `a` and adds 1 to it. In order to get the index in a for loop, you can:

```
for idx, val in enumerate(ints):
    print(idx, val)
```

[Accessing the index in Python 'for' loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/522563/accessing-the-index-in-python-for-loops)

Let me know if my assumption is correct, otherwise provide contents of the two arrays being used in your formula.

To prove that your for loop works:

```
import numpy as np
ten=(1,7,8,10)
ten=np.array(ten)
nine=(3,6,9)
nine=np.array(nine)
lat=range(1,11)
p_new1=[]
H2O_vmr_new1=[]
level=range(1,91)
row=range(0,6)
for j in lat:
    if j in ten:
        print("j in ten: ", end="")
        print(j)
    elif j in nine:
      print("j in nine: ", end="")
      print(j)
```

The result for the above is:

```
j in ten: 1
j in nine: 3
j in nine: 6
j in ten: 7
j in ten: 8
j in nine: 9
j in ten: 10
```